# In MI Device i am getting this issue

Tags: android, android-activity

Getting this error on specific MI Devices activity not start I search
lots of stuff but not worked.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should
>   be opaque

This is Color.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#baffffff</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#8f6fdd</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#8f6fdd</color>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `colorPrimary` to `<color name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</color>`

You can't use a transparent color in the colorPrimary, you need to find another way to do so.